# Map timesTamp to LocalDateTime with error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table in my postgresQL database with a column of type int8 storing a timesTamp value

Column **createdAt** value: **1629137424993**

Mapping JPA

```
@Column(name = "created_timestamp")
private LocalDateTime createdAt;
```

My JPA entity is declaring the LocalDateTime type but I only get the error.

```
repository.findAll();

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type timestamp/date/time: {1}
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.TimestampUtils.parseBackendTimestamp(TimestampUtils.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.TimestampUtils.toTimestamp(TimestampUtils.java:400) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getTimestamp(PgResultSet.java:600) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getTimestamp(PgResultSet.java:2519) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getTimestamp(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3068) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected time to be colon-separated, got ' '
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.TimestampUtils.parseBackendTimestamp(TimestampUtils.java:271) ~[postgresql-42.2.10.jar:42.2.10]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
```

I haven't identified the problem on how can I map a timesTamp value to the LocalDateTime type, I know that for that type I don't need a @Temporal

Comment: Why would you use an `int8` column type to store a `timestamp`?

Comment: it's a bank not managed by my team, we're consuming remotely, so I don't know why the type is int8

Comment: So what is that number?  Is it the number of milliseconds since a particular date in the past?  Number of seconds?  You'll need to know the details, in order to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

A column of type `int8` does not map to any *java.time* type.

Apparently your column holds a count of milliseconds since the epoch of first moment of 1970 UTC (offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). If so, you can [parse that number](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli(long)) as a`java.time.Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millis ) ;
```

`LocalDateTime` class is likely the wrong class for your intentions. That class cannot represent a moment as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset.

As others commented, you should be using date-time types in the database to store date-time values. This is especially true in Postgres which has exceptional date-time handling facilities.